# RegEx works in regexr but not in Python re

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I have this regex: `If you don't want these messages, please [a-zA-Z0-9öäüÖÄÜ<>\n\-=#;&?_ "/:.@]+settings<\/a>`. It works on [regexr](https://regexr.com/) but not when I am using the `re`
library in Python:

```
data = "<my text (comes from a file)>"
search = "If you don't want these messages, please [a-zA-Z0-9öäüÖÄÜ<>\n\-=#;&?_ \"/:.@]+settings<\/a>" # this search string comes from a database, so it's not hardcoded into my script
print(re.search(search, data))
```

Is there something I don't see?

Comment: Maybe add `r` in front of string and copy paste from regexr?
`r"abcd\rawstring"`

Comment: Besides what @jupiterbjy just pointed out, you should add some test data if you want any further help. :)

Comment: Just put the hitherto escaped hyphen in the first or last position of the class where it can't constitute a range: `[a-z...\\-` to ``[-a-z...``. No need to escape it there.

Answer (score 1):

the pattern you are using on regexr contains `\-` but in your exemple shows `\\-` wich may give an incorrect regex. (and add the r in front of of the string as jupiterby said).